# Synchronize project in Eclipse with SVN only source files not others like jar

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am synchronizing code of my project to repo's project. I am interested in only .java files which I made new or made changes..not .jar files.
however when I use synchronize with repo's it shows all source files and .jar files as well,
I just want to see .java files (changed & added).
I am using Eclipse and SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Subclipse version 1.8.4, there is no filter action to set which resources to show. You may want to check if the latest version supports this (version 1.10.5 as of today) http://subclipse.tigris.org/subclipse_1.10.x/changes.html.

However, in the Synchronize view, you can right-click a resource and select "Remove from View". This way you can remove everything except the folder containg your .java files.

If you then edit another .java file it should automatically appear in the Synchronize view to show that it has been changed/added. However if you modify a file of other type (e.g. an XML file or a Jar file gets updated), it will re-appear and you have to remove it from view again.